# operator std::string: why the object cannot output?

Tags: c++, string, typecast-operator

Why this code cannot compile?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    operator std::string () const
    {
        return std::string("Hello world !");
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Foo f;

    std::cout << f << "\n";
}
```

while this one does:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << std::string("Hello world !") << "\n";
}
```

and this one too:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Bar
{
    operator int ()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Bar b;

    std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```

I thought this was the same thing, because of `operator std::string`, but g++ does not compile neither clang++.

Comment: There's `template <CharT, ...> operator<<(basic_ostream<CharT...>&, const basic_string<CharT...>&)` overload that you hope would get called - but that requires template parameter deduction, and said deduction doesn't take user-defined conversions into account. As a result, that overload is not considered viable, and no other overload works out, either.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please add it as answer

Comment: Why is it possible I search for minutes on the site and cannot find the question was still asked?

Comment: you need to perform explicit cast `std::cout << (std::string)f << "\n";`

Comment: You might consider adding to Foo:  "std::string operator ()() { return "Hello World 2 !";  }".   Then in main, use  std::cout << foo() << "\n";  But I like mvidelgauz's cast.